# Why can i only access protected members of a class inside a method of a child(derived class)?

Tags: c++, class, protected, derived-class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class parent
{
protected:
    int main = 0;
};

class subclass : public parent
{
    cout << main;  //error
    void function() //ok
    {
        cout << main;
    }
};
```

I have this code right here where i tried to cout main outside of the function and one inside the function. However i can only access main inside the function but not outside of the function. But why tho?

Comment: Having a line of code in the class but not inside a function is a syntax error, whether it's trying to access a protected variable or not.  You should include the error message in your question.

Comment: `cout << main;  //error` when and how would you expect this line to execute?

Comment: As others have previously mentioned, the ```cout << main;  //error``` can't be executed, since it isn't within a function body. If it helps you to understand, that part of the class is meant to be where variables are declared.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that the statement `cout << main;` cannot appear "directly" inside the *member-specification* of a class. It should instead be inside a member function.

From [class members](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.mem#nt:member-specification):

> member-specification:
>
> - member-declaration member-specificationopt
> - access-specifier : member-specificationopt

As per the above quoted grammer rules, `cout << main` is not allowed to appear directly inside the member specification of a class.